# Кнопка на js при активации изменяется и производит обратные действия

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня на сайте есть кнопка, которая при нажатии убирает 1 секцию.
Я хочу чтобы на ней 2м действием было "убрать footer", и изменить изображение кнопки.

А после при нажатии уже на изменённую кнопку, она при обретала первоначальный вид и footer появлялся.

```js
const switcherPages = document.querySelector('.switcher-pages');
const home = document.querySelector('.home');

switcherPages.addEventListener('click', () => {
    switcherPages.classList.toggle('active');
    home.classList.toggle('active');

    const footer = document.querySelector('#f-id').classList;
    $('#f-id').css('visible','visibility').hide();
})
```

Я написал вот такой вариант, но при повторном нажатии footer не возвращается, и не смог реализовать изменение картинки в кнопке.

new question::

```js
const switcherPages = document.querySelector('.switcher-pages');
const home = document.querySelector('.home');
const footer = document.querySelector('.footer');
let condition = true; 

switcherPages.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (condition) 
    { // block of code to be executed if the condition is true 
        switcherPages.classList.toggle('active');
        home.classList.toggle('active');
        footer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     condition = false; 
    } else
    { // block of code to be executed if the condition is false
        switcherPages.classList.toggle('active');
        home.classList.toggle('active');
        footer.style.visibility = 'visible';
     condition = true; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Так все довольно просто, используй условный оператор и переменную которая будет фиксировать четное или нечетное нажатие произошло на кнопке, и меняй стиль кнопки, как тебе удобно

Comment: Я представляю как это можно сделать, но логическую цепочку всё не получается построить.
Пару часов провозился с marquee jquеry, который по итогу сломался, а в какой моменте неизвестно. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const condition = true; 
    
switcherPages.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (condition) 
    { // block of code to be executed if the condition is true 
    
    switcherPages.classList.toggle('active');
    home.classList.toggle('active');
    const footer = document.querySelector('#f-id').classList;
     
    $('#f-id').css('visible','visibility').hide();
     condition = false; 
    } else 
    {
     // block of code to be executed if the condition is false 
    condition = true; 
    } 
    })
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Ещё один вопрос:
"Как можно сюда добавить задержку, грубо говорят пока .home не вернётся на всю страницу, footer не проявлять ?"

Фрагмент кода добавил выше..